# How equal two objects and return this value to ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two objects (dates)

```
{{vm.currentDate|date:'mediumDate'}} and {{vm.anotherDate|date:'mediumDate'}}
```

How to equal (if are the same)  and value this operation sent to directive in button

```
<button type="submit"  ng-show="VALUE_FROM_OPERATION"></button>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You check if they are equal like this:

```
+currentDate === +anotherDate
```

Comment: if(+currentDate === +anotherDate) { console.log('its the same date dude!'); }